# F# Binding to output while carrying the state

Tags: f#, monads, computation-expression

I am trying to use a Computation Expression to build a list of actions. I need to bind to a value that gets returned from the `getFood` action so that I can register a later step to consume it.

```ml
type Food =
    | Chicken
    | Rice

type Step =
    | GetFood of Food
    | Eat of Food
    | Sleep of duration:int

type Plan = Plan of Step list

type PlanBuilder () =

    member this.Bind (plan:Plan, f) =
        f plan
    member this.Yield _ = Plan []
    member this.Run (Plan x) = Plan (List.rev x)

    [<CustomOperation("eat")>]
    member this.Eat (Plan p, food) =
        printfn "Eat"
        Plan ((Eat food)::p)

    [<CustomOperation("sleep")>]
    member this.Sleep (Plan p, duration) =
        printfn "Sleep"
        Plan ((Sleep duration)::p)

let plan = PlanBuilder()

let rng = System.Random(123)


let getFood (Plan p) =
    printfn "GetFood"
    let randomFood = 
        if rng.NextDouble() > 0.5 then
            Food.Chicken
        else
            Food.Rice
    (Plan ((GetFood randomFood)::p)), randomFood

let testPlan =
    plan {
        let! food = getFood // <-- This is what I am trying to get to work
        sleep 10
        eat food
    }
```

I believe the problem is with the `Bind` but I can't figure out what it is.

```ml
(*
Example result
testPlan =
    (GetFood Chicken,(
        (Sleep 10,(
            EatFood Chicken
        ))
    ))
*)
```

Comment: Don't you have to provide a parameter to the getFood in the let! line? Maybe an empty plan?

Comment: I would think that the Bind function would do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make something like this work, you will probably need a type that has a more monadic structure and lets you store any result, rather than just the plan. I would use something like this:

```
type Step =
  | GetFood of Food
  | Eat of Food
  | Sleep of duration:int

type Plan<'T> = Plan of Step list * 'T
```

Now, `Plan<'T>` represents a computation that produces a value of type `'T` and collects a plan along the way. `GetFood` can produce a plan, but also return the food:

```
let getFood () =
  printfn "GetFood"
  let randomFood = 
    if rng.NextDouble() > 0.5 then Food.Chicken
    else Food.Rice
  Plan([GetFood randomFood], randomFood)
```

Implementing a computation builder is a bit of a black art, but you can now define `Bind` and your custom operations. To be able to access variables in the argument, it needs to be a function as in the `where` or `select` operations:

```
type PlanBuilder () =

  member this.For (Plan(steps1, res):Plan<'T>, f:'T -> Plan<'R>) : Plan<'R> =
    let (Plan(steps2, res2)) = f res
    Plan(steps1 @ steps2, res2)

  member this.Bind (Plan(steps1, res):Plan<'T>, f:'T -> Plan<'R>) : Plan<'R> =
      let (Plan(steps2, res2)) = f res
      Plan(steps1 @ steps2, res2)
  
  member this.Yield x = Plan([], x)
  member this.Return x = Plan([], x)
  member this.Run (Plan(p,r)) = Plan(List.rev p, r)

  [<CustomOperation("eat", MaintainsVariableSpace=true)>]
  member this.Eat (Plan(p, r), [<ProjectionParameter>] food) =
      Plan((Eat (food r))::p, r)

  [<CustomOperation("sleep", MaintainsVariableSpace=true)>]
  member this.Sleep (Plan(p, r), [<ProjectionParameter>] duration) =
      Plan ((Sleep (duration r))::p, r)

let plan = PlanBuilder()
```

This actually lets you implement your test plan:

```
let testPlan =
  plan {
      let! food = getFood () 
      sleep 10
      eat food
      return ()
  }
```

That said, in practice, I'm not sure I would actually want to use this. I would probably just us a `seq { .. }` computation that uses `yield` to accumulat the steps of the plan.

Comment: Normally I would agree with you about just using seq. What isn’t shown here is that in the real word application is that there is a State object being passed through which is a parameter controlling the generation of Id values. That’s what sent me down this path. The real domain is discrete-event simulation that requires unique ids to be generated as the simulation progresses.

Comment: @MatthewCrews That makes sense! I mainly wanted to make sure that a ranom passerby coming across this question does not end up going down the rabbit hole of writing their own computation expressions :-).