# F# passing state into a function in Bind

Tags: f#, monads, computation-expression

This is an evolution of the question I asked here ([F# Binding to output while carrying the state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66681415/f-binding-to-output-while-carrying-the-state)).

I am trying to get the `Bind` method to take a function with this signature `PlanAccumulator<'a> -> PlanAccumulator<'b>`. The `getFood` function is an example of this. I am wanting the `Bind` method to call `getFood` with the `PlanAccumulator<'a>` object.

The challenge is getting the Computation Expression (CE) to call the `getFood` function inside of the `Bind` method using the `PlanAccumulator` that exists at that point in the CE. I'm not sure how to do this but I feel like it should be possible.

```ml
type StepId = StepId of int
type State = {
  LastStepId : StepId
}

type Food =
    | Chicken
    | Rice

type Step =
  | GetFood of StepId * Food
  | Eat of StepId * Food
  | Sleep of StepId * duration:int

type PlanAccumulator<'T> = PlanAccumulator of State * Step list * 'T

let rng = System.Random(123)

let getFood (PlanAccumulator (s, p, r)) =
  printfn "GetFood"
  let randomFood = 
    if rng.NextDouble() > 0.5 then Food.Chicken
    else Food.Rice
  let (StepId lastStepId) = s.LastStepId
  let nextStepId = StepId (lastStepId + 1)
  let newState = { s with LastStepId = nextStepId }
  let newStep = GetFood (nextStepId, randomFood)
  PlanAccumulator (newState, newStep::p, randomFood)

type PlanBuilder (state: State) =

    member this.For (PlanAccumulator (state, steps1, res):PlanAccumulator<'T>, f:'T -> PlanAccumulator<'R>) : PlanAccumulator<'R> =
      printfn "For"
      let (PlanAccumulator(state2, steps2, res2)) = f res
      PlanAccumulator (state2, steps2 @ steps1, res2)

    member this.Bind (input:PlanAccumulator<'a> -> PlanAccumulator<'T>, f:'T -> PlanAccumulator<'R>) : PlanAccumulator<'R> =
        printfn "Bind"
        // THIS IS THE PROBLEM: How do I get the previous PlanAccumulator to 
        // this point in the computation?
        let PlanAccumulator (state1, steps1, res) = input previousAccumulator 
        let (PlanAccumulator(state2, steps2, res2)) = f (state1 res)
        PlanAccumulator (state2, steps2 @ steps1, res2)

    member this.Yield x = 
        printfn "Yield"
        PlanAccumulator (state, [], x)

    member this.Run (PlanAccumulator (s, p, r)) = 
        printfn "Run"
        s, List.rev p

    [<CustomOperation("eat", MaintainsVariableSpace=true)>]
    member this.Eat (PlanAccumulator(s, p, r), [<ProjectionParameter>] food) =
        printfn $"Eat: {food}"
        let (StepId lastStepId) = s.LastStepId
        let nextStepId = StepId (lastStepId + 1)
        let newState = { s with LastStepId = nextStepId }
        let newStep = Eat (nextStepId, (food r))
        PlanAccumulator (newState, newStep::p, r)

    [<CustomOperation("sleep", MaintainsVariableSpace=true)>]
    member this.Sleep (PlanAccumulator (s, p, r), [<ProjectionParameter>] duration) =
        printfn $"Sleep: {duration}"
        let (StepId lastStepId) = s.LastStepId
        let nextStepId = StepId (lastStepId + 1)
        let newState = { s with LastStepId = nextStepId }
        let newStep = Sleep (nextStepId, (duration r))
        PlanAccumulator (newState, newStep::p, r)

// let plan = PlanBuilder()
let initialState = {
  LastStepId = StepId 0
}

let newState, testPlan =
  PlanBuilder initialState {
      let! food = getFood
      sleep 5
      eat Chicken
  }
```

Here's an example of what `testPlan` would be if this worked as desired:

```ml
val testPlan : Step list =
    [
        (StepId 1, GetFood Chicken)
        (StepId 2, Sleep 1)
        (StepId 3, Eat Chicken)
    ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want a plain old state monad, which you can see [here](https://gist.github.com/jwosty/5338fce8a6691bbd9f6f). Using this, I hacked your code as follows:

```
type State<'s, 'a> = State of ('s -> ('a * 's))

module State =
    let inline run state x = let (State(f)) = x in f state
    let get = State(fun s -> s, s)
    let put newState = State(fun _ -> (), newState)
    let map f s = State(fun (state: 's) ->
        let x, state = run state s
        f x, state)

/// The state monad passes around an explicit internal state that can be
/// updated along the way. It enables the appearance of mutability in a purely
/// functional context by hiding away the state when used with its proper operators
/// (in StateBuilder()). In other words, you implicitly pass around an implicit
/// state that gets transformed along its journey through pipelined code.
type StateBuilder() =
    member this.Zero () = State(fun s -> (), s)
    member this.Return x = State(fun s -> x, s)
    member inline this.ReturnFrom (x: State<'s, 'a>) = x
    member this.Bind (x, f) : State<'s, 'b> =
        State(fun state ->
            let (result: 'a), state = State.run state x
            State.run state (f result))
    member this.Combine (x1: State<'s, 'a>, x2: State<'s, 'b>) =
        State(fun state ->
            let result, state = State.run state x1
            State.run state x2)
    member this.Delay f : State<'s, 'a> = f ()
    member this.For (seq, (f: 'a -> State<'s, 'b>)) =
        seq
        |> Seq.map f
        |> Seq.reduceBack (fun x1 x2 -> this.Combine (x1, x2))
    member this.While (f, x) =
        if f () then this.Combine (x, this.While (f, x))
        else this.Zero ()

let state = new StateBuilder()

type StepId = StepId of int

type PlanState = {
    LastStepId : StepId
}

type Food =
    | Chicken
    | Rice

type Step =
    | GetFood of StepId * Food
    | Eat of StepId * Food
    | Sleep of StepId * duration:int

type PlanAccumulator = PlanAccumulator of PlanState * Step list

let rng = System.Random(123)

let getFood =
    state {
        printfn "GetFood"
        let randomFood = 
            if rng.NextDouble() > 0.5 then Food.Chicken
            else Food.Rice
        let! (PlanAccumulator (planState, steps)) = State.get
        let (StepId lastStepId) = planState.LastStepId
        let nextStepId = StepId (lastStepId + 1)
        let newState = { planState with LastStepId = nextStepId }
        let newStep = GetFood (nextStepId, randomFood)
        do! State.put (PlanAccumulator (newState, newStep :: steps))
        return randomFood
    }

let eat food =
    state {
        printfn "Eat: %A" food
        let! (PlanAccumulator (planState, steps)) = State.get
        let (StepId lastStepId) = planState.LastStepId
        let nextStepId = StepId (lastStepId + 1)
        let newState = { planState with LastStepId = nextStepId }
        let newStep = Eat (nextStepId, food)
        do! State.put (PlanAccumulator (newState, newStep :: steps))
    }

let sleep duration =
    state {
        printfn "Sleep: %A" duration
        let! (PlanAccumulator (planState, steps)) = State.get
        let (StepId lastStepId) = planState.LastStepId
        let nextStepId = StepId (lastStepId + 1)
        let newState = { planState with LastStepId = nextStepId }
        let newStep = Sleep (nextStepId, duration)
        do! State.put (PlanAccumulator (newState, newStep :: steps))
    }

let initialState = {
    LastStepId = StepId 0
}

let initialPlan =
    PlanAccumulator (initialState, List.empty)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let _, testPlan =
        state {
            let! food = getFood
            do! sleep 10
            do! eat food
        } |> State.run initialPlan

    printfn "%A" testPlan

    0
```

Output is:

```
GetFood
Sleep: 10
Eat: Chicken
PlanAccumulator
  ({ LastStepId = StepId 3 },
   [Eat (StepId 3, Chicken); Sleep (StepId 2, 10); GetFood (StepId 1, Chicken)])
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to still use Custom Operations?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think you could inherit your `PlanBuilder` from `StateBuilder` and implement them there. I'll see if I can update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Update: I haven't been able to figure out how to do this with custom operations. The problem is that `sleep 10` (without `do!`) attempts to yield a value, which isn't what you want. I've never made custom operations before, though, so someone with more experience than me might be able to figure it out. (That said, you'll still have `getFood` using `let!`, which seems inconsistent, so I'm a bit dubious about the appropriateness of custom operations in this case.)

Comment: This gives me enough to work with. I can refine from here. Thanks for the insight!